# Django, jwt authentication in django view, not just DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'd like to use jwt with django (probably https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)

The library documentation and most web blogs on jwt talks about using jwt on DRF authentication.

But we have Django regular views which are not DRF based.

Can I still use one jwt authentication backend for both DRF and regular django views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. DRF `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` and Django `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` handle auth in Session and Token-based respectively.  Besides that, they are a different namespace.

Comment: I think, I can at least define custom auth backend for django, and reuse the code from jwt auth?

Comment: Ya. you can. I encourage you to do that. But remember, then you far away from the convention. When you far away from convention, community support will be less for you.

Comment: yeah it's weird, if jwt is prefered over session for a reason, why django itself uses session over jwt as a default?

Comment: Both session and JWT has different purpose to serve. For micro-service in REST we use JWT. However, for traditional web app, we use session based auth. In a nutshell, JWT is used for different architecture (REST).

Comment: I don't think it's possible (or very hard) to use jwt for django views.. because we have no way of injecting the auth token in the `<a href />` tag.